# Proving a multivariable function zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)$ be a polynomial of indeterminates $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_m$ with complex coefficients.
I need to show that if $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)=0$ for all nonegative $a_1$, $a_2$,..., $a_m$ then $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)=0$

I started by induction on m=1.It is true  for one variable using fundamantal theorem of algebra then i suppose my supposition true for m-1 and try to prove it true for m where i am stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the result is true for polynomials with $m-1$ indeterminates.

Let $f$ be a polynomial of indeterminates $x_1,...,x_m$ that 
is zero on the positive integers.

If we fix $x_1,...,x_{m-1}$ to have some arbitrary values in the positive integers, we can write a single variable polynomial $q$ as $q(x_m)=f(x_1,...,x_m) = \sum_k x_m^k p_k(x_1,...,x_{m-1})$
for some polynomials $p_k(x_1,...,x_{m-1})$.

Since $q$ is zero on the positive integers, for example, we must have
$q=0$ and hence all the coefficients $p_k(x_1,...,x_{m-1})$ must be zero. Since the choice of $x_1,...,x_{m-1}$ was arbitrary, we must have all $p_k(x_1,...,x_{m-1}) = 0$ on the positive integers. Hence $f=0$.

Comment: By "positive integers", do you mean the set $\mathbb N^m?$

Comment: @zhw.: Yes. The point really was to show the induction step. The particular choice of positive integers just avoids fiddling with degree, etc.

Comment: I get the proof, it's just that it's strangely written to me. Like writing "$q(x_m)=f(x_1,...,x_m)$" for example.

Comment: @zhw.: I modified the text a little, hopefully less strange?

Comment: Nice, I think that's an improvement.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the need of positive integers.

Comment: If a polynomial of degree $n$ is zero on $n+1$ distinct points then it is zero everywhere. That is the basic idea. Since I don't want to bother fussing with degrees, I just choose the positive integers. If any polynomial is zero on the positive integers, it is zero everywhere, regardless of degree. $zhw.'s answer is another approach.

Comment: Another thing, the coefficients $p_k (x_1,x_2,..,x_{m-1})$ are zeroes because we considered that $q(x_m)$ of one variable is zero thus making {${1,x_m,...,x_m^s}$} for some $s$ makes up my basis and thus the coefficients are linearly independant hence equal to zero?

Comment: I don't follow your question. If $q(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then $q=0$ and so all the coefficients of $x^k$ in the expression $q(x)$ must be zero. In this case, the coefficients are $p_k(x_1,...,x_{m-1})$ for the particular values of $x_1,...,x_{m-1}$. However, since these were arbitrary, we have  $p_k(x_1,...,x_{m-1})=0$ for all $(x_1,...,x_{m-1}) \in \mathbb{N}^{m-1}$ and then we hit the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

The hypotheses imply $f\equiv 0$ in an open ball. By translating $f,$ we can assume this open ball is $B(0,r).$ Then for each unit vector $u\in \mathbb R^m,$ the function $p_u(t)= f(tu)$ is a polynomial on $\mathbb R$ that vanishes on $(-1,1).$ Hence $p_u$ vanishes identically. This is the same as saying $f\equiv 0$ on every line through the origin. Hence $f\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb R^m.$